# SAPUI5 DatePicker / DateRangePicker. Min + Max dates

Tags: sapui5

I can set the dateValue attribute in the Date Pickers, but unfortunately the user can still enter a date before it.

Is there any way I can set an minimum (and maximum) date on the datepicker?

Regards

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately until the current [Version 1.36](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8d36a5a5f57a409792fb36a3f4940cdb.html) of SAPUI5 the control `sap.ui.commons.DatePicker` does not provide such functionalities. But you still can handle this yourself with the *change event*.

```
var minDate = "12121991";
var maxDate = "12122020";
var oDatePicker = new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker();
oDatePicker .attachChange(function(oEvent) {
  if(oEvent.getParameter("invalidValue") || this.getYyyymmdd() < minDate || this.getYyyymmdd() > maxDate) {
      oEvent.oSource.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
  } else{
      oEvent.oSource.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I've had to do the validation manual as you suggest. Not ideal from a UI perspective, but it works. Do you know if there's plans to include it in the future@

Comment: Honnestly, i don't have the certain answer if SAPUI5 team will provide that features in the future or not.. If it is vital for you project ,you can write me,maybe i have a better solution.

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks a lot for your help.